# Using Java's 11's scripting features, can I execute a .java file directly from java code?

Tags: scripting, java-11

I'd like to use the built-in java compiler module to have my java application call an uncompiled .java class like the way "java MyProgram.java" or JShell can without (visibly) compiling it into a class.

I'm really hoping for an API like:

```
Class myClassInstance=java.compiler.Compile("MyClass.java")
```

but I'm sure it's not going to be THAT easy.

I'm trying to avoid running the compiler, creating a class, dealing with classloaders, etc. Also I know there are external packages out there that can do this, but I'd rather stick to pure Java 11 sdk.

There is a javax.script.ScriptEngine that would be perfect if it supported "Java" as a scripting target without downloading a separate driver, but I haven't seen anywhere that it can.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Scripting engine is not for Java code

Comment: How do you want to use this? Because there's the `jdk.jshell` module you could use, but I'm not sure if you can use the variables/classes/methods outside the `JShell` instance. There's also the `java.compiler` module, where you could compile to memory, then define a simple class loader to load those classes or maybe use [`MethodHandles.Lookup#defineClass(byte[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.Lookup.html#defineClass(byte[])).

Comment: You want to run the compiler and create a class but “avoid running the compiler and creating a class”?

Comment: Does not seem to have a public API for it.

Comment: The “the new ability to directly execute .java source files from the command line” does exactly what you want to avoid, “running the compiler, creating a class, dealing with classloaders”. I don’t know what you mean with “pragmatic access to jdk.compiler or jdk.shell” you can access these modules like any other module, whether you’re pragmatic while accessing them, is an issue of your own personal mindset.

Comment: @Holger Exactly, I'd like to leverage what they are doing since they already did the hard work.  I can see the packages there but can't figure out how to use them efficiently from the docs or online, hence asking a question on SO.  Also, need to stop commenting from phone with spell check.

Comment: I’m not sure what kind of documentation you expect. [`jshell`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/jdk.jshell/jdk/jshell/package-summary.html) provides you with code examples, so does [`JavaCompiler`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html). Of course, if you want to do exactly what the launcher does, you can simply use `new ProcessBuilder("java", "MyClass.java").inheritIO().start().waitFor();`

Comment: @Holger That is really good points.  I don't want to shell out like that though.  The jshell example in the docs isn't really simple and doesn't really do the job (Can't get the values out).  The example is interesting but it's more about creating a REPL--it MIGHT have a solution, I just couldn't figure out the right API calls, that's why I asked here. The JavaCompiler doesn't fix any of the dynamic class loading/reloading issues so it really doesn't fit (I just mentioned it thinking there might be something in there I missed)